# Good TTCN-3 resources

Tags: ttcn

Does anyone know any good resources for learning TTCN-3?

All I've seen (through Google) is either toy demos that does not implement real codecs to a real language (i.e. no test adaptors so that your test cases actually talks to the networ), or the ETSI language references which are dry and not exactly helpful for someone to learn to navigate an existing test system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this book, An Introduction to TTCN-3, http://amzn.com/0470663065

Answer (score 2):

I started with this: http://ttcn-3.net/tutorial.html, there's a complete test case example, explained step by step and its implementation in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have some documentation from the TRex TTCN-3 refactoring and metrics tool

http://www.trex.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/trac/wiki/Documentation